# PHP scrape an html page

Tags: php, html, scrape

So I am just trying to scrape an HTML page with PHP.  I looked on Google for how to do it, and I uuse the `file_get_contents()` method.  I wrote a little bit of code, but I am already getting an error that I cannot figure out:

```
    $page = file_get_contents( 'http://php.net/supported-versions.php' );
    $doc = new DOMDocument( $page );
    //print_r( $page );

foreach ( $doc->getElementsByTagName( 'table' ) as $node ) {
    print_r( $node );
}
```

The first, commented out print_r statement DOES print the page, but the foreach loop should be getting every table in $node but it is printing nothing.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My advice would be to use Simple HTML Dom Parser; http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: why you trying to mix php with javascript

Comment: I'm writing a WordPress plugin

Comment: @Kaylined What is wrong with the `DOMDocument` parser? It is able to do this, he just made a little mistake.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it; the simplehtmldom just provides a nice wrapper imo.

Answer (score 2):

You load your `DOMDocument` wrong, you need to either `->loadHTMLFile()` or something a like. See the [documentation here](http://php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php).

Here is what you need to do instead.

```
<?php
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTMLFile("http://php.net/supported-versions.php");
    foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('table') as $table){
        var_dump($table);
    }
?>
```

The line `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` makes sure there are no errors thrown when the html is loaded. As `nav` and `section` tags are not supported as *"correct"* html for instance.

Comment: Finally!  I'm still learning php dom and tried many convoluted examples but this one was simple enough for me to successfully adapt to my needs.